# Is diffuse reflectance measurement superior to transmittance for determining band gap energy?

Tags: spectroscopy

Some papers report band gap estimation using [Diffuse Reflectance Measurement](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6091/what-is-the-principle-of-diffuse-reflectance-spectroscopy-behind-band-gap-measur) (e.g. [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10971-011-2582-9)).

Why would the results of diffuse reflectance be superior to regular transmittance measurement? And why *diffuse* reflection and not specular reflection?

[image]([source](http://www.ssi.shimadzu.com/products/product.cfm?product=uv_accy_solid_guide1))